# Comment answered a question, mark as solved

Tags: support, comments

I posted a question and the answer was in the comments.

How can (should) I close the topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell them to post an answer - or well, just copy the comment as an answer referencing the person who posted the comment.

Add to it a little, and its all good.

If I did that and the commenter posted an answer I'd consider letting them having the selected answer as fair play.

Comment: Answering unloaded questions like these must feel like a breath of fresh air :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be closed as a dupe. Was soooo tempting to post an answer as a comment